# How to use to kubectl to patch statefulset envFrom

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a Kubernetes `Statefulset` and im using `envFrom` to add environment variables from ConfigMaps and Secrets, by defining configMapRefs and secretRefs in an 'extra-values.yaml' file and including that file in my `helm install` command.

The `Statefulset.yaml` snippet:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name | lower}}
          envFrom:
          {{- if .Values.envFrom }}
          {{- toYaml .Values.envFrom | nindent 10}}
          {{- end }}
```

The values.yaml file has a single `envFrom:` line with no children, and the `extra-values.yaml` file contains the configMapRefs and secretRefs:

```
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
    name: my-configmap-name
- configMapRef:
    name: another-configmap-name
- secretRef:
    name: my-secret-name
- secretRef:
    name: second-secret-name
```

The Helm install command:

```
helm install myapp /some-folder/myapps-chart-folder -f extra-values.yaml
```

What I want to do is install `myapp` without the `extra-values.yaml` file, and then use the `kubectl patch` command to add the configMapRefs and secretRefs to the statefulset and its pods.

I can manually do a `kubectl edit statefulset` to make these changes, which will terminate and restart the pod(s) with the correct environment variables.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out the correct syntax and parameters for the `kubectl patch` command, despite hours of research, trial, and error, and repeated headbanging.  Help!

Comment: You said as lot of what _didn't_ work, but you haven't included in your question what you _did_ try and what outcome it produced for you. Regardless, you're looking for `kubectl -n WHATEVER patch -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"WHATEVER", "envFrom":[{"configMapRef":{"name": "my-configmap-name"}}, ...]}]}}}}' statefulset/WHATEVER` right?

Comment: Why not use `helm upgrade -f extra-values.yaml` to add in the values (and then the current state of the system can be recorded in source control)?  Why this particular workflow of installing a partly-configured system, then completing the configuration?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I did not think to use `helm upgrade` but that also works, and the syntax is easier than `kubectl patch`, thanks!  To answer your second question, the Kubernetes app is install on-premise at the customer site, and then configured based on the customer's environment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel) for the answer, which contains the clue to what I was missing.  Basically, I completely overlooked the fact that the `containers` element is an `array` (because my `statefulset` only specified one container, duh).  In all of the `kubectl patch` command variations that I tried, I did not treat `containers` as an array, and never specified the container name, so `kubectl patch` never really had the correct information to act on.

So as suggested, the command that worked was something like this:

```
kubectl patch statefulset my-statefulset -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"name":"the-container-name", "envFrom": [{"configMapRef":{"name":"my-configmap-name"}}, {"configMapRef":{"name":"another-configmap-name"}}] }] }}}}'
```

Comment: this way seems incorrect as it replaces array, while in most cases if you want to patch you would like to add additional item